# Sign an .app bundle / bin without Xcode in macOS

Tags: macos, rust

What do I need to do? I need clear, concise instructions. I've developed a Rust program, wrapped it in a bundle. I do not want to wrap it in Swift and use Xcode to sign and notarize. I would like to distribute the app outside of the app store. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you seen `cargo-bundle`: https://github.com/burtonageo/cargo-bundle

Answer (score 1):

On the command line this is accomplished through the codesign and notarytool components of Xcode Command Line Tools.

Codesign:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Notarization:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow